# lower limit to lower feedback resistor value in a transimpedance amp?

Tags: transimpedance

[image]

The upper limit to the gain setting feedback resistor value in a transimpedance amp is dictated by op amp rail voltage but is there lower limiting factor for the value also?

I changed this feedback resistor value to a much lower value in an audio DAC with very high current output (~30mA), this reduced max gain to safe levels  as desired but caused caused severe distortion and I'd like to learn why.

Op amp is OPA1612, the recommended op amp in DAC's datasheet.

DAC is AK4499

Comment: Question: Are you using a classical voltage.opamp as a transimpedance amplifier (as shown in the figure) or are you using instead a current-feedback amplifier (CFA)?

Comment: yes, its a voltage feedback opa1612

Comment: Specifically, what chip is the DAC.

Comment: Added the details of op amp and DAC to the post

Comment: @Jay NO, what is the DAC used inside the box that acts as a current source. DAC means digital to analogue converter and isn't just a box of bits. Down at the circuit board level where you are messing with the OPA1612 there is a circuit that feeds it and that circuit is a chip called a DAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The op amp input can only sink or source so much current, equally the amount decreases as it approaches the supply rails, (there is a resistance in the output),

Once it reaches the point where it cannot swing any closer to the supply rail due to that resistance, you get distortion.

edit: if your signal is bidirectional, there may also be cross over distortion, with these current levels its not an easy issue to work around, and may be improved by choosing an alternative op amp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lowest distortion, you need to identify the SHORT CIRCUIT OUTPUT of the opamp, per the datasheet, and then operate at 25% or 33% of that value at MOST.

Why?

The protection circuits are not precise, and they usually involve bipolar junctions and bipolar transistors that START TO TURNON. In STARTING TO TURNON, the gain of the opamp is impaired and the distortion soars.